# Will Laravel work on php 5.3.3 server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

good day! Just a quick question about laravel since we are planning to use laravel on our new project, the problem is the client is using php 5.3.3 on their server. I know that laravel works on php 7 but the question is will it still work on php 5.3.3? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4 check the docs..

Comment: The best approach would be to convince the client to update their PHP, rather than run a no longer supported, vulnerable version.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2#server-requirements the lowest supported version starts from PHP 5.4

Comment: I see. thank you for your comments. well honestly speaking we tried to convince them. but the problem is they don't want to as it will affect most of their applications/softwares. but maybe running on a virtual server will make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the oldest version available in the documentation located at https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/#server-requirements

It states

```
PHP >= 5.4
```

So I would say No.

This is due to found security risks in various versions of PHP so Laravel has a baseline for PHP.

Comment: I see. thank you for your comments. well honestly speaking we tried to convince them. but the problem is they don't want to as it will affect most of their applications/softwares. but maybe running on a virtual server will make it work?

Comment: They need a new server or virtual server. Maybe try a digital ocean droplet

Comment: Or a homestead instance that uses virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Docker, you can use a PHP7 Docker container with the latest stable version of Laravel, and then you will not touch the PHP 5.3 version

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will try looking at this one.